# .htaccess rewrite image urls

Tags: image, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to figure out how to redirect all image urls like this:

https://example.com/images/FILE.PNG

to this:

https://example.com/old-site/images/FILE.PNG

Is there an easy way to do this with .htaccess? I've looked around, but couldn't find a post anywhere with a similar scenario of adding a sub directory and don't understand htaccess rules well enough to write it myself.

Any and All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this one-liner rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(/images/.+)$ /old-site/$1
```

Comment: That comment won't help you. What URL did you enter in browser and what error did you get? Also show your complete .htaccess in question.

Comment: I literally didn't have any results.

Answer (score 2):

Using URL Rewrite in .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?images/(.*)$ /old-site/images/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I literally didn't have any results.